# Inequality based on increasing hazard rate

Tags: probability, analysis, inequality

Suppose $F$ is a c.d.f. over $[0, 1]$ with positive and continuous density $f$. Assume the hazard rate $\frac{f}{1-F}$ is increasing. Does the following inequality hold
$$x  (1 - F(x))^2 > F(x) \times \int_{x}^1 (1 - F(y)) \mathrm{d} y, \,\, \forall x \in (0, 1) ?$$

I numerically tested uniform distribution and it is true. I also tried $f = \frac{e^{1-x}}{e - 1}$, it is also true. So, it seems to me that this inequality holds, but do not know how to show it. Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A counterexample*:

Let
$$F(x) = 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{1 - x}}.$$
Then
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{1 - x}}$$
and
$$\frac{f}{1 - F} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}.$$
The conditions are satisfied.

However, when $x = 4/5$,
$\mathrm{LHS} = \frac45 \mathrm{e}^{-8} \approx 0.000268$
and $\mathrm{RHS} = (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-4})(\frac15\mathrm{e}^{-4} - \mathrm{e}\mathrm{Ei}(1, 5)) \approx 0.000532$.

---

*Remarks*:

Note that $\frac{f}{1 - F} = \frac{- (1 - F)'}{1 - F} = (-\ln (1 - F))'$.
Thus, $-\ln(1 - F)$ is convex.
Let $-\ln(1 - F) = G$.
Then $F = 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-G}$.
The conditions beomes: $G(0) = 0, G(1^{-}) = \infty$
and $G$ is convex on $[0, 1)$.
The desired inequality becomes
$$x\mathrm{e}^{-2G(x)} > (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-G(x)})\int_x^1
\mathrm{e}^{-G(y)}\,\mathrm{d}y.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome.